# ReactJS Use SetInterval inside UseEffect Causes State Loss

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval, use-effect, clearinterval

So I am writing a product prototype in create-react-app, and in my App.js, inside the app() function, I have:

```
const [showCanvas, setShowCanvas] = useState(true)
```

This state is controlled by a button with an onClick function; And then I have a function, inside it, the detectDots function should be ran in an interval:

```
const runFaceDots = async (key, dot) => {
const net = await facemesh.load(...);
setInterval(() => {
  detectDots(net, key, dot);
}, 10);
// return ()=>clearInterval(interval);};
```

And the detectDots function works like this:

```
  const detectDots = async (net, key, dot) => {
...
  console.log(showCanvas);
  requestFrame(()=>{drawDots(..., showCanvas)});
  }
}};
```

I have a useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
runFaceDots(); return () => {clearInterval(runFaceDots)}}, [showCanvas])
```

And finally, I can change the state by clicking these two buttons:

```
 return (
     ...
      <Button 
        onClick={()=>{setShowCanvas(true)}}>
          Show Canvas
      </Button>
      <Button 
        onClick={()=> {setShowCanvas(false)}}>
          Hide Canvas
      </Button>
    ...
    </div>);
```

I checked a few posts online, saying that not clearing interval would cause state loss. In my case, I see some strange behaviour from useEffect: when I use onClick to setShowCanvas(false), the console shows that console.log(showCanvas) keeps switching from true to false back and forth.

[a screenshot of the console message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9BKr.png)

you can see initially, the showCanvas state was true, which makes sense. But when I clicked the "hide canvas" button, and I only clicked it once, the showCanvas was set to false, and it should stay false, because I did not click the "show canvas" button.

I am very confused and hope someone could help.

Comment: I don't see where you are setting the state.

Comment: in `return(...)` of the functional component app() , I have a button `<Button onClick={()=> {setShowCanvas(false)}}>Hide Canvas</Button>` so when I click that button, the state of showCanvas should be set to false?

Comment: please add it to the code. Your example should be reproducible. Meaning we should at least see from your code what is your login, and where the error could have occured. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: After you set to false, where do you set to `true` again? What is the state that is lost? Can you clarify your question.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. I added a screenshot of the console, and hope this can clarify my question a bit. So in my case, the showCanvas state is `true` initially (this makes sense), and I click the `hide canvas` button, the state is set to `false`, and it should stay `false` until I click the `show canvas` button. But if you see the screenshot, you will see that the state keeps switching from `false` to `true` back and forth, though I only clicked `hide canvas` once and nothing else...

Comment: It seems that at every interval, the showCanvas state is initialized to `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using useCallback for `runFaceDots` function - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

And ensure you return the setInterval variable to clear the timer.

```
const runFaceDots = useCallback(async (key, dot) => {
     const net = await facemesh.load(...);
     const timer = setInterval(() => {
        detectDots(net, key, dot);
     }, 10);
     return timer //this is to be used for clearing the interval
 },[showCanvas])
```

Then change useEffect to this - running the function only if showCanvas is true

```
useEffect(()=>{
       if (showCanvas) {
       const timer = runFaceDots(); 
        return () => {clearInterval(timer)}
       }
       }, [showCanvas])
```

Update: Using a global timer

```
let timer // <-- create the variable outside the component.

const MyComponent = () => {
     .....
    useEffect(()=>{
           if (showCanvas) {
           runFaceDots();  // You can remove const timer here
            return () => {clearInterval(timer)}
           } else {
               clearInterval(timer) //<-- clear the interval when hiding
           }
            
           }, [showCanvas])

    const runFaceDots = useCallback(async (key, dot) => {
         const net = await facemesh.load(...);
         timer = setInterval(() => { //<--- remove const and use global variable
            detectDots(net, key, dot);
         }, 10);
         return timer //this is to be used for clearing the interval
     },[showCanvas])

     .....
}
```

Comment: This definitely did something but still not quite working. I added `console.log(showCanvas)` in `useEffect(()=>{...},[showCanvas]}`, and the console returns ideal results. However, I also added a `console.log(showCanvas)` in `timer = setInterval(() => {...},10)` function, but the console always returned `true` (whichi is the initial value of `showCanvas`) even if I clicked `hide canvas` button...

Comment: updated the answer. You can use a global variable to hold the timer, and clear the interval when u hide canvas.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!